# Plotting datestr time

Tags: matlab, time

in my .txt I have columnt "time", which is in format:

8/9/2012 11:21:43:739

Now I want to plot data vs time, but I'm getting error
"Conversion to double from cell is not possible."

So problem is my timestamps, how can I change it so I can plot my data (maybe are problems aslo miliseconds at end of timestamp)??

Comment: You can try to plot the date's datenum() instead of the date. See http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html. Unfortunately, I can only give code answers. I don't know if Matlab can do this purely through its GUI without writing code.

Comment: Yes i also tried this datenum(time), but get this error; i think problem is miliseconds

Too many time fields in 8/9/2012 11:21:43:739.

Comment: I think I know what's causing this. I edited my answer and brought it back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem seems to be the millisecond field. It's in a wrong format. You have:

```
11:21:43:739
```

Instead, you need this:

```
11:21:43.739
```

Milliseconds should be separated by a dot, not a colon.

If you wish to keep the current format, then you need a custom format specifier when converting the date string. For example:

```
datenum('8/9/2012 11:21:43:739', 'dd/mm/yy HH:MM:SS:FFF')
```

Comment: well I import data and it's one column!!! beetween them is also space as you said; This is all I have; I just need to convert this column so matlab can understand this is date and time...

Comment: Then we need to see your code, especially the part where you read from the file :-)

Comment: Ok, but even if I separate this to 2 columns and want to plot just "time" vs my "data", I can't do that...:
you can try plot(11:21:43:739,11.5) for example....

Comment: I just use "import data" in matlab...I try with code but have problems so I use this second option, but I can manually separete datum and time in notepad...this is not problem, but as I said even if I do that how can then plot ??? I need plot(datum+time, data)

Comment: You can try to plot the date's `datenum()` instead of the date. See http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html. Unfortunately, I can only give code answers. I don't know if Matlab can do this purely through its GUI without writing code.